# cors not setting my cookies to browser but works fine in postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, axios

I'm successfully able to see my JWT token cookie in postman. Although the same is not the case with google chrome.

I'm using node and express in backend and react in the front end.

This is my server side signup post request:

```js
router.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
    const user = new userDB()
    user.username=req.body.username;
    user.email=req.body.email;
    user.password=req.body.password;
    
    
    user.save()
      .then(() => { 
        
        const token= createToken(user._id)
        
        res.cookie('jwt',token, { maxAge: maxAge*1000})
      
        res.send('User Added succesfully'); //send user id to front end using res.json(user._id)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        const errors= handleErrors(err);
        res.send(errors)
  
        
  }) 
  } )
```

Here is my app.js server file:

```js
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cors=require("cors")
var postRouter = require('./routes/postController');
var commentRouter = require('./routes/commentController')
var authRouter = require('./routes/authRouter')
var {checkUser}=require('./middleware/authMiddleWare')
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cors())

app.use('*', checkUser)
app.use('/apiEndpoint', postRouter);
app.use('/apiEndpoint/CREATE/comment', commentRouter);
app.use('/apiEndpoint/CREATE/user', authRouter);



module.exports = app;
```

Here is my axios POST request:

```js
const handleSubmit=(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault()
        axios.post('http://localhost:2000/apiEndpoint/CREATE/user/login', {
            email:Login.email,
            password:Login.password
          })
          .then(function (res) {
            console.log(res)
            setResponse({...response, email: res.data.email, password: res.data.password})
          })
        
        setResponse({...response, email: '', password: ''})   

        
        
    }
```

Im able to find my JWT token cookie in postman but there is absolutely no cookie in the browser.

Comment: are you seeing any errors in the browser?

Comment: After some fiddling around with random stuff in axios, cors, the error disappeared and there was no error at all. The er: access to xmlhttprequest at 'http://localhost:2000/apiendpoint/create/user/signup' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by cors policy: response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: the value of the 'access-control-allow-origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. the credentials mode of requests initiated by the xmlhttprequest is controlled by the withcredentials attribute.

Comment: But that did not fix it

Comment: have you tried adding: withCredentials: true,

Comment: Thanks. I added {withCredentials:true} and also in my server app, i have added this :const corsConfig = {
    origin: true,
    credentials: true,
  };
  
  app.use(cors(corsConfig)); 

this is has worked for me. I'm getting my JWT token and also no error. I'm getting an error if i remove this corsConfig. The error is the same as written in the above comment.